# JQuery .serializeArray() How to get access data in Json Object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jquery .serializeArray() to get all the `<input>` in a `<form>`.
I'm putting the Json object that comes out of `.serializeArray()` into jquery `.data()`

How do I find the data I want out of the Json object?

Jquery `getJson()` needs a url but I'm I already have the Json Object.

Answer (score 2):

The [`serializeArray()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method doesn't create JSON data. It creates an Array of Objects, each of which has a `name` and a `value` property.

How you get the data out depends on what you need. For direct access to a particular item, you access it like you would with any other Array and Object.

```
myData[1].value;
```

This gets the `value` of the second item in the Array.

If you needed to iterate over them, you could use [`jQuery.each()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$.each( myData, function() {
    var name = this.name;  // the name property in the current iteration
    var value = this.value;  // the value property in the current iteration

    console.log( name, value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.serializeArray() returns an array

```
[{
   name: "a",
   value: "1"
 },{
   name: "b",
   value: "2"
 },{
   name: "c",
   value: "3"
 },{
   name: "d",
   value: "4"
 },{
   name: "e",
   value: "5"
 }
]
```

this code relies on [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var formArray = $('#formid).serializeArray();
formArray.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[cur.name] = cur.value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

to yield this object

```
{
    a: "1",
    b: "2",
    c: "3",
    d: "4",
    e: "5"
}
```